# How do I create a link using C#?

Tags: c#, hyperlink

Could anyone tell me how to create a link from a LinkLabel in Visual Studio?

Say I'm trying to make the program pull up a browser window to www.google.com (in their default browser). How would I do that? I got the following from some example code I found:

```
        HttpWebRequest head_request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");
        head_request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:6.0a2) Gecko/20110613 Firefox/6.0a2";
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)head_request.GetResponse();
```

But what I have doesn't do anything. If anything, it makes my browser go into a state of unresponsiveness.

I have

```
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
```

up top. Is that right? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do like something below:

```
ProcessStartInfo sInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("http://mysite.com/");  
Process.Start(sInfo);
```

An article about it: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320478

Attach it to a link:

```
protected void hyperlink_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ProcessStartInfo sInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("http://mysite.com/");  
   Process.Start(sInfo);
}
```

Note: If you can't see it, then you should declare `using System.Diagnostics;` namespace.

Comment: When I try to type ProcessStartInfo in, it tells me the keyword doesn't exist. Should I be including something else as well?

Comment: You should declare `using System.Diagnostics` as `ProcessStartInfo` is defined under that namespace.

Comment: But if you are using Visual Studio, it will inform you about it and assist you how to add it.

Comment: Okay, i got a basic link to work. Is there a way I can attach it to a LinkLabel in a single command? I tried 
    linklbl.Process.Start("link");

but that didn't work

Comment: You need to put that piece of code under an event handler which will run when you click on the button. (EventHandler will handle the event raised once you click on the Button, LinkLabel, etc.)

Comment: @Ben What's `linklbl`??? `Process` is most likely not a property of `linklbl`... it's a class in `System.Diagnostics`. You can't mix and match random code chunks like that.

Comment: If it helps you and want it help others, please mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The code below will open google.com in the default browser. You can call this code from anywhere. The click event of a button would be a good place to test it out!

```
Process.Start("http://google.com/");
```

Comment: is that the only line I need? i apologize, i'm relatively new at coding

Comment: Yeah this is the only thing you need to go to that link on a browser. Process will be automatically started with a default web-browser.

Comment: the keyword Process isn't listed as something that's allowed. Am I missing something outside of this like one of the "using" statements?